# How to get the c array from c# via dll?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, dll

I output something to a array  written in c , then I hope to get the information from c# calling via dll, but failed. No warnnings but I can note get the informaton  correctly. Test code as follow :

@ips store the output information

```
UDPDLL_API int get_by_csharp_tst(char *** ips){
    char **ip = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    *ips = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
    if(ips == NULL){
        perror("overflow");
    }
    ip = *ips;
    for(i =0 ; i <10 ; i++){
        *ip = (char*)malloc(16);
        memcpy(*ip,"255.255.255.255",16);
        *ip++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

calling from c# as follow :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace dll_call
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("udpdll.dll",EntryPoint="get_by_csharp_tst")]
        public static extern int get_by_csharp_tst(byte [,] ai);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            byte[,] ips = new byte[10, 16];
            Program.get_by_csharp_tst(ips);
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(ips);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you again. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: A pointer to a pointer to a pointer.. yowza. What does it return when you're debugging?

Comment: `[,]` is not what you think it is

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: That would be `ref string[]` (or similar)

Comment: @leppie That's how I envisioned it but wasn't sure..

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible API.

For starters, never allocate memory on the native side, if you cannot free it there too.

But if you have to, then read on.

Change the signature to `public static extern int get_by_csharp_tst(out IntPtr[] ai);`

Call it like:

```
IntPtr[] ai; // do not allocate, you are doing it on the native side already
get_by_csharp_tst(out ai);
// as we know the size, just use it
string[] results = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  results[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ai[i], 16);
}
// you need to free the memory you allocated natively here, else memory leak.

foreach (var s in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

**Note:** It will be potluck even when specifying the length (`16`) as you never clear the allocated memory and there is no guarantee the last element will be `\0`.